# How can I commit all new folders and files in directory?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

When trying to commit changes to a directory with tortoisesvn I need to manually check-off each new file and folder I want to commit, including the contents of a folder. This is obviously ridiculous, as  can't manually check-off 112 files and folders.

How can I commit all new files and folders to the SVN directory? Also, how can I have tortoisesvn commit all new files/folders by default and then allowing me to check-off the ones I don't want to commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://tortoisesvn.net/images/CommitDlgSpellCheck.png

On this screenshot (can't paste here) **checkbox "Select/desect all"** is cleanly visible

Comment: 403: Access Forbidden

Comment: I managed to find the button due to your answer despite the 403. Not quite sure how I missed that... I just didn't think I could click it.